# What's the best word that captures "a simplified representation of a complex process"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I've seen and heard the word 'heuristic' used in this sense, but each time I look up the definition, it doesn't quite stretch to fit. A synonym might be 'a stand-in'. Something between a metaphor and a concrete symbol. I'm thinking specifically in the context of cognitive error. For example, "Alex uses her feelings about her mother as a ______ for her relationship with all women".
Thoughts? Is there a word for this?

Comment: Sorry to ask but a bit more context by way of other examples would be useful. The word that comes to my mind is *Model*. If you could tell me why that will not do it would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: simplification [ahem]

Comment: Sounds like _model_, or in a different context, maybe _proxy_.

Comment: In your example sentence I would maybe use *road map,* *guideline,* *misguidance,* maybe even *an expectation*. As an answer to the question in the title, a *simplification* or *simplified model* seems to fit. The "cognitive error" that you mention seems to point more towards *misguidance* or *false presumptions*.

Comment: An analogue? It's not very common to see it as a noun, but Lexico defines this as "A... thing seen as comparable to another" and I'm fairly sure I've seen the word in technical journals to mean 'a representation of something else'.

Comment: The example sentence confuses the issue. What seemed to be one concept prior to it can now be interpreted as several different things. In addition to those other words suggested, the blank in the sentence could be filled by words such as **crutch**, **exemplar**, or **paradigm**. There are so many different types of possible words here, that the question needs a lot more clarification to limit it to just one or the other.

Comment: "Stereotype" or "mold"

Comment: Possibly "abstraction"

Answer (score 4):

Given your example sentence

> "Alex uses her feelings about her mother as a ______ for her relationship with all women."

I would suggest

> **template** *n*
> 2. anything that determines or serves as a pattern; a model: *You can use my notes as a template for employee evaluations*.
> <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/template)</sub>

So:

> "Alex uses her feelings about her mother as a template for her relationship with all women."

Answer (score 0):

***Pattern***

> something that is used as an example, especially to copy
>
> - The design is so good it's sure to set the pattern for many others. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pattern))

See also

> a reliable sample of traits, acts, tendencies, or other observable characteristics of a person, group, or institution
>
> - a behavior pattern
> - spending patterns
> - the prevailing pattern of speech ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pattern))

So you could say:

> Alex uses her feelings about her mother as a ***pattern*** for her relationship with all women.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean simplified in a symbolic way you might use the word "emblematic".

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest the word 'model' as a model of A is a simplified representation of A.

"Alex uses her feelings about her mother as a model for her relationship with all women"

Answer (score -2):

A "simplified representation of a complex process" involves a degree of rationalization. 'Rationalization' may be the word to use in the provided example.